# Building Excel uploader in MVC, Should I save Excel file to db or file/web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I allow user to upload one excel file at a time. After the upload, the code will validate then save portions of the excel file to an existing database (sql server).

Should I save the excel file to the db, then pull it out and process it, or is it better to save to a temp directory on the web server, process/save the data, then delete the file?

Edit: If I end up saving the file to the DB, is it better to go the binary route (save to byte array, then save) or can I use a regular string array or file stream?

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion its best to do this approach.

The answer will be based on your requirement, since you said you will process whats inside excel then this is my suggestion.

1. Save the file in a file/web server
2. Save the path of the file saved in SQL Server

Here is why:

1. To process the file from your code will be easy no need for additional process to access the file and no special coding needed.
2. You can physically access the file if needed.
3. Putting files on the database will increase its load, huge possibility of slowing your whole application down.
4. Database will be bigger so back ups will be slower
5. Talking about costs, DB strorage is more expensive than file system storage